# Is iTunes uploading my music to the "cloud"?

Tags: itunes, icloud

I notice that in my iTunes there is a blue cloud icon next to some of my music, for example:

[image]

Does this mean Apple is uploading my personal music to "the cloud"? (Normally I load music only via CD-ROMs that I have bought). If so, how can I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 1):

No, it means that song is available for download *from* the "cloud" to your local drive: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203564